# How do you set the background image of a back of a tile when using shell tile schedule?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using ShellTileSchedule to set the background image of my live tile every hour. Every hour I am also looking to update the back of my tile with another background image. I am hoping to update both images at the same time.

It seems like ShellTileSchedule does not support background image of the back of a tile. Any work arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the front and back of the tile on a periodic basis you'll have to create a background agent to do it.

Comment: Background agents do not run beyond 14 days. What do you do then?

Comment: @CodeToGlory simply restart them every time the user enters the app. You can also prompt the user to open the app (via a toast) if they haven't run it for a few days.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by creating a ShellTileScheduler with no problem. All you have to do is create a StandardTileData and set the BackBackgroundImage property.

[WP7 Tile Tutorial](http://rodrigueh.com/wp7-live-tiles-with-background-agents)

Comment: Yes you can set background image this way initially but not update it as part of the schedule.